# Chart.js - How to set a line chart dataset as disabled on load

Tags: chart.js

Using chart.js v2, is it possible to mark a dataset in a line chart as being disabled on initial load?

[image]

Didn't find an option for it in the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart).

Comment: I don't think it exists an option for that. You should remove the 'disabled' dataset and manually add an entry in your legend.

Comment: @bviale Ok thanks, suspected that was the case.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Yes, there is a "hidden" flag in ChartJS.
eg.

```
data:
{
        datasets: [
        {
            data: [1,2,3],
            label: 'My First Dataset',
            hidden: true,
        },
        ],
}
```

See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/689

Comment: It's so `hidden` that 3 years later and it's still not in the docs

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6069#issuecomment-573438435) says that `hidden` should not be used, and instead `setDatasetVisibility` is preferred.  But in the near-term using `hidden` sure did the job for me, so thank you!!

Comment: Is it also possible to completely disable the button? So I can't be clicked either. I want to lock some data behind a paywall.

Comment: @Mathijs if you want to hide data behind a paywall then rather only send the relevant data to the front end if the user hasn't got the necessary subscription.

Comment: I do do that, but I still want to show the label of the other dataset, turn it off and make it unclickable, so that the user knows they are missing something. I fixed it with a custom click event

Answer (score 8):

The accepted solution has the downside, that hiding/unhiding signals might sometimes fail after initializing the chart like that.

It might be a better idea to change it in the current metadata of the dataSet, which holds the actual data that is used by the chart:

```
chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataSet, i) => {
  var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);

  meta.hidden = (<your-condition-here>);
});

this.chart.update();
```

Comment: This solution works great for data updated and/or if you want to change the "hidden" property dynamically. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ***`angular-chartjs`***, then you can add the properties of the dataset in the `chart-dataset-override` property:

For example:

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
  <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = true;

angular.module("app", ["chart.js"])
  .controller("ChartCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
    $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

    $scope.data = [
      [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];

    $scope.datasetOverride = [{}, {
      hidden: true,
    }];
  });
```