# Chart.js - Hide line using label string after load

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), I have a line chart that is displaying datasets compiled in a .net web app.

Is it possible to set a line as hidden/disabled once the data is loaded, based on the label name?

There is a [hidden flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846177/chart-js-how-to-set-a-line-chart-dataset-as-disabled-on-load) in chart.js that enables a dataset to be hidden on load, but this is set when initially defining the dataset. As the data has already been defined within the view, I cannot use this flag. E.g.

```
var viewsByMonthChartCtx = new Chart(viewsByMonthChartCtx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['February 2017','March 2017'],
            datasets: 
                 [ { label: 'Home', data: [100,120 ] }, // I want to set 'hidden: true' to the Home dataset post initialization
                   { label: 'Search', data: [200,240 ] } ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide a dataset after the chart has been initialized (and rendered), then you still use the dataset `hidden: true` property.  You simply just have to access the dataset from your chart instance and set the property to true.

Here is an example where a dataset matching a label is hidden 5 seconds after the page loads.

```
// the dataset label we want to hide after chart is initialized
var hiddenLabel = 'My Second Dataset';
var timerDuration = 5;

// hide a dataset after X seconds
setTimeout(function() {
  var indexToHide = -1;  

  // find which dataset matches the label we want to hide
  myLine.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
    if (e.label === hiddenLabel) {
      indexToHide = i;
    }
  });

  // get the dataset meta object so we can hide it
  var meta = myLine.getDatasetMeta(indexToHide);

  // hide the dataset and re-render the chart
  meta.hidden = true;
  myLine.update();
}, timerDuration * 1000);
```

As you can see, you can just iterate over the datasets to find the index of the dataset with the matching label, then you simply set the hidden property to true and update the chart.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/WpRbyy) that demonstrates a full working example.

With that said, it's not clear why you would want to do this after the chart is hidden.  If you already know which dataset you want hidden at page load time, then you could just assemble your data and options chart config dynamically and set the hidden flag to true programmatically.  Here is an example.

```
// the dataset label we want to hide
var hiddenLabel = 'My Second Dataset';

// build our data and options config (if needed you could build the datasets dynamically from dynamic data (this example is static)
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First Dataset",
      backgroundColor: chartColors.red,
      borderColor: chartColors.red,
      data: [5, 10, 25, 15, 10, 20, 30],
      fill: false,
    }, {
      label: "My Second Dataset",
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: chartColors.blue,
      borderColor: chartColors.blue,
      data: [5, 0, 12, 5, 25, 35, 15],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Hide Dataset Matching "My Seconds Dataset" After 3 Seconds'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Month'
        }
      }],
    }
  }
};

// iterate over our datasets to find the one we want to hide
config.data.datasets.forEach(function(e) {
  if (e.label === hiddenLabel) {
    e.hidden = true;
  }
});

// instantiate the chart
var myLine = new Chart($('#canvas'), config);
```

Comment: This works - thank you. The reason that I cannot load this prior to getting the data is because the data is generated in .net and outputted to a view; I do not have access to the .net code but I can update via JS. But you are correct, it would be a lot easier to hide it prior to loading the view!